# How to unit test GWT+SmartGWT?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, maven, selenium, smartgwt

I am Unit testing on the client side of a **GWT+SmartGWT** application.

First I tested with **GwtTestCase**. Too long for unit testing a huge application. **GwtTestSuite** doesn't help. It still takes too much time to execute. (more, it asked me to start a  browser when it's testing)

Then **gwt-test-utils** : Great framework. Sadly, my javassist version is 3.5 and need at least the 3.11. Javassist is used by gilead so I can't touch this. So, no gwt-test-utils...

I saw **Selenium**. That's just great. With htmlunit driver, it's fast and useful. Simplest way to test a webapp. Problem here is SmartGWT generates it's own IDs when it generates the web page. So I can't get the TextItems and fill them since those IDs are constantly changing. I found that it could be solved by using setID() before the initialization of the widget. But that's the ID of the scLocator and not an HTML ID. Selenium doesn't want to work with scLocator.

**=> Is there a simple way to accept scLocator with Selenium ?**
(And when I say simple, it must be simple... I'm not a specialist in Java...)

Could someone help me to unit test the application ? It's coded in Java, it's huge and I have to cover ~70% of the code (25k lines of code)

Some more specs :
Maven is used to compile.
I'm not touching at the server side.
Tests must be faster than GwtTestCase and Suite :/

I hope my problem is clear, I'm not a native english so sorry for mistakes I may do :x

Comment: just a comment - gwt-test-utils would *never* work with SmartGWT because it requires creating Javascript substitutes for JSNI code.  This would be a tremendous effort since SmartGWT is primarily a wrapper around SmartClient

Comment: Yes I contacted one of the maintainers of the project. He told me it will never work :/
So I'm back with selenium.

Comment: I made a blog about Unit Testing smartGWT applications using Selenium. You should have a look if you're interested ^^ http://noobdevelopper.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

< defaultUserExtensionsEnabled>true< /defaultUserExtensionsEnabled>
< userExtensions>[path to user-extensions.js]< /userExtensions>

There we go. I managed to make it work. (With the selenium-maven-plugin in the < configuration> tag)

Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Could you please provide some context to your answer? Which of your originally proposed approaches does it apply to?

Answer (score 1):

We provide Selenium extensions and a user guide for them in the SDK, under the "selenium" directory at top level.

If you download 3.1d (from smartclient.com/builds) there's even more documentation including some samples for JUnit.

Do not use ensureDebugId() (won't have an effect at all). Never try to work with DOM IDs (won't work).

Best practices information in the Selenium user guide explains when you should use setID().

Answer (score 0):

> I found that it could be solved by using setID() before the
>   initialization of the widget. But that's the ID of the scLocator and
>   not an HTML ID.

Why don't you try:

```
widget.ensureDebugId("some-id");
```

From the Java docs for *ensureDebugId()*:

> Ensure that the main Element for this UIObject has an ID property set,
>   which allows it to integrate with third-party libraries and test tools

Comment: Still doesn't work. Seems that it's an internal ID. setID() fill the scLocator and ensureDebugID() seems to be an internal reference. I really don't know how to get through this x__x

Comment: You are not correct. ensureDebugId() sets the HTML element's ID. Unless some external code is modifying it afterwards.

Comment: Well I tested it, and it still doesn't work. The ID is present, but in the scLocator. Maybe I did something wrong with my tests, but when I inspect the element, it's still the same ID. More it would cost a lot of code refactoring because the project is huge. Setting an ID for every single field I want to test would be hard...
Btw javassist is now on 3.15 and it works fine with gilead4gwt so I'll give gwt-test-utils one more try. And then maybe if it doesn't work I'll get back to ensureDebugId(). Maybe that's not a logical way, but gwt-test-utils' test are a lot faster than selenium.